# Two callbacks after animating single element

Tags: jquery, animation, callback

I'm scratching my head as to why I'm getting two callbacks when running this function.

```
lE = $(this).clone().appendTo('body');

// Hide submenu
$('nav>ul>li>ul').fadeOut(100, function() {
    // Animate clone
    $(lE).animate({ 'top': '160px' }, 100, function() {

        console.log('aaa'); // PRINTS TWICE IN CONSOLE

        $(lE).animate({ 'left': '150px' }, 300, function() {
            $(lE).addClass('lE');
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see I start by assigning a clone to lE. Surely lE can only be a single element at this point no?

I then proceed to run a three animations within each other but the second animation get's called back twice. I can't understand why.

Comment: What event is this code running under?

Comment: is there fiddle to play with :?

Comment: What is `this` in line `lE = $(this).clone()`?

Comment: Add var in front of lE?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's a button click

Comment: @Satpal event happens on button click, so I'm cloning the html/css of the button I just clicked to create an element that looks exactly like it and then animate it

Comment: Since you cloned `lE` and appended it to the body, there are two of them in the dom. When you animate multiple elements, you get a callback when each one is complete. See the marked duplicate for examples of how to get around it.

Answer (score -1):

I've got problems while using multiple chain callbacks before. Try to use `setTimeout` instead of function callbacks. This method worked on me before.

```
lE = $(this).clone().appendTo('body');

$('nav>ul>li>ul').fadeOut(100);

setTimeout(function() {
    $(lE).animate({ 'top': '160px' }, 100);
},100);

setTimeout(function() {
    $(lE).animate({ 'left': '150px' }, 300, function() {
        $(lE).addClass('lE');
    });
},200);
```